# Non-const member reference is mutable on const object?

Tags: c++, class, struct, reference, member

Given the following:

```cpp
struct S
{
    int x;
    int& y;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 6;
    const S s{5, i}; // (1)
    // s.x = 10;     // (2)
    s.y = 99;        // (3)
}
```

Why is `(3)` allowed when `s` is `const`?

`(2)` produces a compiler error, which is expected. I'd expect `(3)` to result in a compiler error as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is `s.y = 99` allowed when `s` is `const`?

The type of `s.y` for `const S s` is not `int const&` but `int&`. It is not a reference to a const int, but a const reference to an int. Of course, all references are constant, you cannot rebind a reference.

What if you wanted a type `S'` for which const object cannot be used to change the value `y` refers to? You cannot do it simply, and must resort to accessors, or any non-const function (e.g. `operator=`):

```
class U
{
    int& _y;
public:
    int x;
    void setY(int y) { _y = y; } // cannot be called on const U
};
```